# How to use amp-iframe for geolocation purposes?

Tags: amp-html

Since amp-iframe can be used for geolocation purposes based on this link, does the use of setting allow="geolocation" give access to HTML5 geolocation API or does it allow to simply run certain types of scripts?

Answer (score 0):

The standard HTML attribute allow="geolocation" does the below:

1. It allows the iframe to ask for permission
2. It by default does not give permission to the iframe

As a side note,  AMP now supports native geo targeting based on **amp-geo** component which will provide an approximate country-level geolocation interface. The amp-geo component uses the country from which the request originated in the form of an ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code which is determined from the client's IP address.
This [resource link](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-geo) details out the functionalities of  in further detail. We encourage you to take a look at the same.